# Updating Location field through EWS removing room resources

Tags: office365, exchangewebservices, office-js

A: Our scheduling software in integrating with Exchange users' calendar appointments by subscribing to room resources. Our software adds the relevant room resources to the users' appointments as required resources.

We have a c# service using EWS that write information to the location field of the appointments with room information.

In the old UI the room resources and location field were independent entities. In the new UI, the two have been amalgamated into one.

in order to replicate this make sure you first use exchange web service to update the location field of an appointment.
as an example we are using this

private void SetAppointmentDetails(Appointment appointment)
        {

```
        appointment.Location = "floor number :" + " room number" 
        appointment.Update(ConflictResolutionMode.AlwaysOverwrite);

    }
```

Then try to edit the appointment in new webui

Bug : invited room resources get removed which causes our integration to fail.

We have tried to read the location field and append our data instead of overwrite but it did not work. We suspect this is because in the new UI the location field has been changed from a text field to a collection of objects/strings.

Comment: Have you tried to update Resources collection? Location is derived from the resources, which are BCC recipients on the MAPI level.

Comment: Hi Dmitry, yes we do update the resources collection. but as it integrate with our system we change the location string, but resource remains same and we do not have any issue with current UI and no resources are removed if location field changed by EWS. However with the new UI which is not release yet its behaving differently. That's what we want to know if Microsoft is planning to change this behavior where location and resources has to be same.

Comment: Only Microsoft can answer that. Try to open a support case with them.

Comment: Hi Dmitry, Thanks for your suggestion. We are in process of doing that. so in mean time if outlook exchange web services or outlook addin team can confirm that if they can replicate or confirm that if this is the behavior to be expected from going forward